# Anybody builds openmonero in docker image?

Tags: monerod, mymonero, build, api

I have to build docker image with [openmonero](https://github.com/moneroexamples/openmonero). Also, I'm trying use this [dockerfile](https://github.com/guardaco/openmonero-docker). But nothing works. Maybe you have solution or detailed instructions how to build openmonero from last sources. Thx.

Comment: I'd suggest to post full build logs. This enables other to more easily nail down the issue.

Comment: Now I have this error 
```[ 87%] Built target myxmr
Scanning dependencies of target openmonero
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openmonero.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_CORE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND', needed by 'openmonero'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/openmonero.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openmonero.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: My guess would be, that you have to tell CMake, where to find the monero source code.

Comment: Follow the instructions on https://github.com/moneroexamples/openmonero first then build your own Dockerfile.